# Syntax error in bytes(" ".format(), encoding="utf-8")

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.8

When running this:

```
import hashlib

hash1 = hashlib.md5(b'admin:Pentester Academy:asdds').hexdigest()
hash2 = hashlib.md5(b'GET:/lab/webapp/digest/1').hexdigest()
nonce = "526f295f84bcafc67598cd8e760a9cc5"

response_unhashed = (bytes("{}:{}:{}".format(hash1, nonce, hash2)), encoding='utf-8')
response_md5hashed = hashlib.md5(response_unhashed).hexdigest()

print(response_md5hashed)
```

I get this...

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\Infosec\Notes\Programming\example.py", line 7
    response_unhashed = (bytes("{}:{}:{}".format(hash1, nonce, hash2)), encoding='utf-8')
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where's the syntax error? Checked some of the bytes() and format() documentation but couldn't find any clues.

Comment: You've added *too many* parentheses, so you have `(bytes( < ... >), encoding='utf-8')` you want `bytes(< ... >, encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are parentheses that are in wrong order.

Try

```
bytes("{}:{}:{}".format(hash1,nonce,hash2), encoding = "utf-8")
```

Instead of

```
(bytes("{}:{}:{}".format(hash1, nonce, hash2)), encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
import hashlib
hash1 = hashlib.md5(b'admin:Pentester Academy:asdds').hexdigest()
hash2 = hashlib.md5(b'GET:/lab/webapp/digest/1').hexdigest()
nonce = "526f295f84bcafc67598cd8e760a9cc5"

response_unhashed = bytes("{}:{}:{}".format(hash1,nonce,hash2), encoding = "utf-8")
response_md5hashed = hashlib.md5(response_unhashed).hexdigest()

print(response_md5hashed)
```